# Normally distributing particle velocities

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

I'm trying to set up initial conditions for a collection of N particles distributed on the surface of a unit sphere so that they are uniformly distributed in position and their velocities are normally distributed so that the temperature of the overall system is some fixed number T. I thought of doing this by trying to distribute the magnitude squared of the velocities ($v^2$) so that the rms speed is proportional to T, i.e.
$$\sqrt{E(v^2)} =    aT,$$
where E(X) denotes the mean of the variable X and a is some positive number.

The particles are restricted to move along the surface, so I know that each particle's velocity is given by $$\vec{v} = v_{\phi}\hat{\phi}+v_{\theta}\hat{\theta}.$$
Thus
$$E(v^2) = E(v_{\phi}^2+v_{\theta}^2) = E(v_{\phi}^2)+E(v_{\theta}^2).$$ Now if I choose $v_{\phi}$ and $v_{\theta}$ so that they are both normally distributed with mean 0 and variance a^2T^2/2, I get that $$E(v_{\phi}^2) = (v_{\theta}^2) = E(v_{\phi})^2 + Var(v_{\phi}) = a^2T^2/2$$ and thus $$E(v^2) = a^2T^2/2 +a^2T^2/2 = a^2T^2$$ as desired. However when I try to use this method to generate initial conditions, even for very high temperatures it seems like a large amount of the particles start out with zero speed, which doesn't make sense to me intuitively because shouldn't there be less and less particles starting with zero speed as you increase the temperature? I'm really not sure how to come up with a correct way to do this.

Comment: You are defining $v_\phi$ by $v_\phi=r \dot \phi  \sin\theta$ I hope?

Comment: Yes I am defining it that way. Since it is a unit sphere, r=1.

Answer (score 0):

The usual particle energy distributions of a 2D ideal gas have their maximum at zero energy. Both for a finite number of particles $p(E) = (N-1)\frac{(E_{tot}-E)^{N-2}}{E_{tot}^{N-1}}$, and for an infinite number of particles $p(E) = \frac{1}{kT} e^{-\frac{E}{kT}}$, which corresponds to [velocity distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#Relation_to_the_2D_Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) $p(v)=\frac{m v}{k T} e^{-\frac{m v^2}{2 k T}}$. So generally, it is normal to have a large number of low-energy particles, with a much smaller number being above the equipartiton level.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would you be able to provide some references for where I can read more about this? I can't seem to find anything that states that this is the case and about initial particle velocity distributions.

Comment: I've provided 2D distributions, since the particles in your system move along the 2D surface. That was probably some sorce of confusion. It may also be interesting for you to read [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-023-30636-6.pdf), since your system is also axisymmetric. I'm not sure, but the initial circular gas flow may appear not decaying in time.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you start with the Hamiltonian of the system $H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{r})$ (it is not quite clear what it is in your case), and write the Boltzmann probability distribution as
$$
w(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{r})=Z^{-1}e^{-\frac{H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{r})}{k_BT}},
$$
so that the temperature is already encoded in in the distribution.

Note however that the magnitude of velocity is not distributed in the same way as velocity - in particular, it distribution cannot be Gaussian, even if the distribution of velocities is.

E.g., let us consider a two-dimensional system with particle energy
$$
H(v_x,x_y)=\frac{m(v_x^2+v_y^2)}{2}
$$
Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution then gives us
$$
w(v_x,v_y)\propto e^{-\frac{m(v_x^2+v_y^2)}{2k_BT}},
$$
that is $v_x,v_y$ are indeed distributed according to the Gaussian law with $\langle v_x^2\rangle=\langle v_y^2\rangle=\frac{k_BT}{m}$.

The magnitude of the velocity $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$ is however distributed differently (by transforming to polar coordinates):
$$
w(v_x,v_y)dv_xdv_y\propto e^{-\frac{m(v_x^2+v_y^2)}{2k_BT}}dv_xdv_y=ve^{-\frac{mv^2}{2k_BT}}dvd\phi\propto w(v,\phi)dvd\phi,
$$
and after integrating out the angle, we would have
$$
w(v)\propto ve^{-\frac{mv^2}{2k_BT}}
$$